# Ngx material timepicker - determine if empty or 00

Tags: angular, timepicker

I uses ngx material timepicker and encounters a problem-
After erase value, field does not return value to null but to '00:00'.
I did not find a way to figure out if field is setted to '00:00' or was cleared.
Any idea how can I do this?

My html:

```
<ngx-timepicker-field #timepicker
 [conterolOnly]="true"
 [confirmBtnTmpl]="okBtn"
 [format]="24"
 [(ngModel)]="value">
</ngx-timepicker-field>
```

My TypeScript:

```
private _value;
set value(time) {
 this._value = time;
 this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
get value(){
  return this._value
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you try to erase value, can you add the code to your question ?

Comment: User erase it using backspace key.   
(I added typescript code)